# asp.net session cookies without the use of session

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am a little bit confused about the use of the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.

When not using session state in my application I thought that the cookie was 
set on every response, just with a new value. In the moment I use sessions in my app, the cookie's value (session-id) would stay the same.

Actually when not using session in my app, the cookie's value is still the same (indicating the same sessionid).

**Q1**: Why is session-cookie value the same when not using session in app?

**Q2**: Why is there a session-cookie sent on every response when when not using session in app?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you turn off SessionState - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306996